# Java, how can I make a jar to edit another jar

Tags: java, file-io, executable-jar

I've come up with an idea to make a program for my school, where teachers enter questions and answers A, B, C, D, etc. and when it's done to create a jar file which will be the actual test program. Now I know how to make the program up to the point where all data from the teachers is collected, but then I don't know how to proceed. My idea is that the teachers' jar will be in the same folder as an example ready 'test jar'(with other questions and answers stored in it's variables) and when the teacher is ready their jar will simply edit the 'test jar's variables and then they could give the 'test jar' to students, though I have no idea how to edit a jar file's code from another jar. How can I approach this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: make an output file from the input jar and then import this file into the other jar to use.

Comment: yeah, that sounds nice, though can you redirect me to a source about how I can import a file into a ready .jar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically a jar is just a Zip file.

Java provides good support for zip archives via the types located in the

> java.util.zip

package.

your code will go something like this:

```
ZipOutputStream outStream = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(zipFileName));

 // Add a zip entry to the output stream
 outStream.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(myEntryName));

 // add data to your entry by writing to outStream
 ......
 ......
 //Close zip entry and file streams
 outStream.closeEntry();
```

And a full [example.](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/creating-zip-and-jar-files-in-java/)

Comment: remember to use Java 7 in the case of using java.util.zip . There have been some nasty bugs (with encodings) in the versions before.

Answer (score 0):

if your trying to make a quiz with customizable questions and answers, I suggest you use a text file to store the options (questions and answers and maybe type of question like multiple choice or enter a valie or choose one).

For the format of the file can use xml or simply use java.util.Properties, using its store and load to save to a file.

Your properties can be "totalNumberQuestions", "question1" "questionType1" "question1option1" etc

Now in your main program, look for a file:
* if progrtam started with args.length > 0 look for a file with arg[0] in a seperate try catch, so even if not there you show a error message and continue

- if not found or no args called "data.txt" in the same folder as your program meaning:
  File f = new File("data.txt");
  if(f.exists()){ //read inpout stream
- else from the class loader in the jar getClassLoader().getResourseAsStream (look up actual function name in java.lang.Class

This way a user can use your second jar to create their data.txt and then pack it with the main jar that asks the questions or simply keep it in the same folder or pass it as a parameter when starting the program.

You can repack a jar using the jar command

```
jar ufMv quiz.jar  data.txt
```

To create a new zip using jar:

```
jar cvfM quiz.jar data.txt yourPackage.*.class
```

Answer (score 0):

You could better make up a database of the questions and answers. The teachers program will write in the database, the child's program will read the database.